# Flexbox and responsive iframes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to mantain the 16:9 ratio when I insert responsive `iframes` inside a `flexbox`.

```css
.video-media-youtube-inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div[class^="video-media-youtube-inner-vi"] {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  height: 0;
}

div[class^="video-media-youtube-inner-vi"] iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-media-youtube">
  <div class="video-media-youtube-inner">
    <div class="video-media-youtube-inner-vi01">
      <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/8AHCfZTRGiI"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="video-media-youtube-inner-vi02">
      <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/8AHCfZTRGiI"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="video-media-youtube-inner-vi03">
      <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/8AHCfZTRGiI"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But, as you can see from the snippet, the `iframe` width is shrinked correctly but the `height` remain always the same. Is it possible to mantain the 16:9 ratio in `flexbox` items?

Comment: What do you mean by the 16:9 ratio? The `iframe`, individually, has a width of 784 and a height of 881. That's not 16:9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an extra `<div>` around the `<iframe>`s:

```css
.video-media-youtube-inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div[class^="video-media-youtube-inner-vi"] {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}

div[class^="video-media-youtube-inner-vi"] .sixteen-by-nine {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  height: 0;
}

div[class^="video-media-youtube-inner-vi"] iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-media-youtube">
  <div class="video-media-youtube-inner">
    <div class="video-media-youtube-inner-vi01">
      <div class="sixteen-by-nine">
        <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/8AHCfZTRGiI"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="video-media-youtube-inner-vi02">
      <div class="sixteen-by-nine">
        <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/8AHCfZTRGiI"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="video-media-youtube-inner-vi03">
      <div class="sixteen-by-nine">
        <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/8AHCfZTRGiI"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

On another note - Perhaps you are using a convention I'm not familiar with, but I think it would be more standard and also more maintainable to just use a consistent class like `video-media-youtube-inner` for your inner `<div>`s and then assign them unique `id`s (`vi01`, `vi02`, `vi03`). That way, you could just access them via `.video-media-youtube-inner` in your CSS, or `#vi01` if you need to target a specific one.

Comment: It's SMACSS. If they're using SCSS it looks like this:


`.video-media-youtube {`

`&-inner { `

`&-vi01 {`

(Sorry for the formatting, I guess comments don't support good code formatting)

Comment: Hmmm, maybe I'm missing something but I can't find any documentation on the `div[class^="foo"]` pattern being recommended/included as part of SMACCS guidelines. I know it's part of the standard CSS spec as valid styling (https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/REC-selectors-3-20181106/#attribute-substrings), but I haven't seen this used before and don't really see any benefit to it vs. standard class/id usage.

Comment: But to your point, if this is being compiled from SCSS, that alleviates the maintainability concerns.